# How to "properly" invoke executable from usr/bin via Starlark?

Tags: bazel

In one of my rules, I want to unzip a file via `unzip -d`so that I can access some headers.

Currently, I am doing so by using whatever unzip is on my PATH.

```
ctx.actions.run(
      ...
      executable = "unzip",
)
```

Alternatively, I could use `/usr/bin/unzip` to avoid relying on my PATH. However, it's unclear what the idiomatic approach should be. Based on my reading of the docs, I would ideally have some sort Bazel binary target for `unzip` that the rule would invoke. It's somewhat unclear, though, how I would go about defining that binary target, perhaps an `sh_binary`.

Comment: any thoughts? It's still unclear to me whether I should use an absolute path or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right solution would be having an unzip utility in your repo. (Either in the source tree or imported as an external repository.)

Without that, I think the most principled approach is to write a repository rule that looks up `unzip` from the PATH using `repository_ctx.which` (or just expects "/usr/bin/unzip" to exist) and creates a BUILD file ([`repository_ctx.file`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html#file)) with a `sh_binary` that wraps the `unzip` tool.

In both cases you have to add a label attribute "_unzip_tool" to the consuming rule:

```
"_unzip_tool": attr.label(
                   executable = True,
                   cfg = "host",
                   default = Label("@unzip//:unzip_tool"),
               ),
```

and use it like so:

```
ctx.actions.run(
    ...,
    executable = ctx.executable._unzip_tool,
)
```